# How to transform this dict output?

Tags: python, list, dictionary

I have a little bit of a logic game. I have list with following dicts in each listnode.

```
{1: [1,{'X': -0.48595, 'Y': 0.0, 'Z': 0.56283},
     2,{'X': -0.48595, 'Y': 0.0, 'Z': -0.6}],
 2: [2,{'X': -0.48595, 'Y': 0.0, 'Z': -0.6},
     4,{'X': 1.14756, 'Y': 0.0, 'Z': -0.6}],
 3: [4,{'X': 1.14756, 'Y': 0.0, 'Z': -0.6},
     9,{'X': 1.14756, 'Y': 0.0, 'Z': 0.8}]}
```

What I want? List with nodes of lists as below:

```
[{'Id': 1, 'Nodes': [{'Id': 1, 'Position': {'X': -0.48595, 'Y': 0.0, 'Z': 0.56283}}, 
                     {'Id': 2, 'Position': {'X': -0.48595, 'Y': 0.0, 'Z': -0.6}}]}, 
 {'Id': 2, 'Nodes': [{'Id': 2, 'Position': {'X': -0.48595, 'Y': 0.0, 'Z': -0.6}}, 
                     {'Id': 4, 'Position': {'X': 1.14756, 'Y': 0.0, 'Z': -0.6}}]}, 
 {'Id': 3, 'Nodes': [{'Id': 4, 'Position': {'X': 1.14756, 'Y': 0.0, 'Z': -0.6}}, 
                     {'Id': 9, 'Position': {'X': 1.14756, 'Y': 0.0, 'Z': 0.8}}]}]
```

How can I make that transformation? I'm keep trying modifying my code, but everytime something's wrong.

```
mem_list = []
for x in range(len(list_temp)):
    mem_loc_list = []
    for key in list_temp[x]:
        nodes_list = []
        member = {}
        member['Id'] = key
        node_dict = {}
        for y in list_temp[x][key]:
            if type(y) == int:
                node_dict['Id'] = y
            else:
                node_dict['Position'] = y
            nodes_list.append(node_dict)
        member['Nodes'] = nodes_list
        mem_loc_list.append(member)
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Using list comprehension you can do it like this:

```
[[{"Id": k, "Nodes": [{"Id": v[i], "Position": v[i+1]} for i in range(0, len(v), 2)]} 
 for k,v in data.items()] for data in list_temp]
```

Comment: mem_list=[{"Id": k, "Nodes": [{"Id": v[i], "Position": v[i+1]} for i in range(0, len(v), 2)]} 
 for k,v in list_temp.items()]      <- When I want to make this line of code I have "AttributeError: 'list' object has no attribute 'items'" error.

Comment: @D4w1d - then the input is not a dictionary like you described in your example data

Comment: @nitred - This is not a good edit

Comment: Input shown above is only one node in the long list. Edit: list_temp is a list that contains such dictionaries. I want to transform it to the list of lists shown in the second code-block.

Comment: @D4w1d - in that case you can perform the line in answer for each item of that list. See update